# Request body json decimals removed

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have an issue with the JSON I have to get from my POST call.

I actually have to compare 2 signature strings which both contain a JSON part at one point. Let's say they're like :

```
val signature = "someText+" + Json.stringify(jsonValue) + "+anotherText"
```

The 2 signatures I have are supposed to be similar but the `jsonValue` I get from request.body has its decimals with 0 removed (like `12.0` becomes `12`) so the signatures are different.

Is there any way to avoid the decimal removal? Thanks!

Comment: Is deserializing not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "normal" behavior of the JSON because there is no difference between 12.0 and 12 in JSON standard.

[From wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

> Number: a signed decimal number that may contain a fractional part and
>   may use exponential E notation, but cannot include non-numbers like
>   NaN. The format makes no distinction between integer and
>   floating-point. JavaScript uses a double-precision floating-point
>   format for all its numeric values, but other languages implementing
>   JSON may encode numbers differently.

So you do not need to bother what you will send further 12.0 or 12 because there are no such things like "integer" or "float" in JSON. The next conversion on the next step could flip-flop it again.

**UPDATE**

You say you need it for generating a signature. 
Someone will check this signature, and that someone also could convert this JSON to some types and back (why not? just like you do it), and could receive a different result. Different but correct. The main point here is that you can not use JSON to generate a signature (and it's not only about numbers, it just one of the point). The thing you do - you use String for creating signature, not JSON.

Now about string, you need to get the raw request body. In Scala:

```
def index = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
    val jsonAsString = request.body
}
```

Comment: Yes I see what you mean but the thing is that I have to build a String signature using this and many other fields so a string with .0 or not changes everything as I have to compare it with another one which has it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried to look at the Play body parsers and `parse.tolerantText` did the job to force convert the json to string, and the decimals are here :)